# SQL avoid many to many groups with identical members

Tags: c#, sql

I have a list of conditions.
These conditions can be grouped.
When creating groups, I want to avoid duplicate groups, meaning they have the same members.
the ID's are unique identifiers, there is a unique constraint on the Name of the condition.

[image]

For example, I have 3 conditions, being "Painted", "Oiled", "Protected".

I want to make groups of Painted & Protected and Oiled & Protected. Since there are multiple applications, it is possible that they want to create the groups at the same moment

In code, I first try to retrieve the group with the matching members. If there is no group found, we create it. With multiple threads or applications this introduces a race condition where there can be created in the database.

Is there a way to avoid this in SQL or in code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A good place to start is [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search) the site to see if there's any answers here already. When you post a question, make sure to [follow the suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best possible answers. Make sure your question has [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). One way that we've solved this problem for some clients is by creating a "Windows Service" that manages the database for things like this.

Comment: "meaning they have the same members" - at the moment, it looks like there aren't *any* members; to clarify: is it the case that there's some non-zero number of non-ID columns, and you don't want duplicates *of those unique combinations*? or...?

Comment: This way or other the bad news is the whole table CGM must be locked so that no parallel updates are allowed

Comment: From the database level, if you do not want duplicates you should create a unique key having both the ConditionGroupID and the ConditionGroupMemberID columns.

Comment: @Serg I was hoping there was a more elegant solution. I hoped it was possible to force some uniqueness through SQL so the insert of the members would fail

Comment: @Cleptus This does not take away the possibility to create another group with the same members, only the possibility to add a condition twice to a single group

Comment: The simple reason why it is not possible to have a straightforward unique constraint like this is because it covers multiple *rows* as a single unique entity. There is no simple mechanism in SQL for such a thing, nor could I envisage an efficient way to enforce it. It would need a full table scan every time.

Comment: If this question about preventing race conditions or querying if a set already exists before creating?

Comment: You either should use a lock to prevent duplicates in c# or create a stored procedure in sql that assigned the new properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a relational division-no remainder problem. A set based approach is as follows:

A) Assume that `(conditiongroup_id, condition_id)` pairs are unique

B) Convert the set of values to be inserted into a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #temp (condition_id int NOT NULL UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO #temp (condition_id) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);
```

C) Perform relational division:

```sql
SELECT   conditiongroup_condition.conditiongroup_id
FROM     conditiongroup_condition
LEFT JOIN #temp AS temp ON conditiongroup_condition.condition_id = temp.condition_id
GROUP BY conditiongroup_condition.conditiongroup_id
HAVING COUNT(temp.condition_id)                     = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp)
AND    COUNT(conditiongroup_condition.condition_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp);
```

If this query returns one or more rows then the `conditiongroup_id` returned contains *exactly* all three conditions. This logic could be coded inside your application and inside an insert trigger. Table value constructor `VALUES()` could be used instead of temporary table.

Comment: This one did the trick for me.
I use it with the table value constructor when adding the conditions in a single insert.
You are also correct that it can be used in a trigger. A check constraint does not work because this checks every insert individually, meaning if there is already any of those condition soly in a group, every insert of a group containing that condition would fail

Answer (score 0):

this could be help you.

IsDuplicate is a UDF for verifying ConditionGroupMembers, then reference that UDF from a check constraint.

```
create function dbo.IsDuplicate()
returns int as 
begin
    declare @result int=0
    ;with cte as 
    (
        select ConditionGroupId, string_agg(ConditionGroupMemberId ,', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ConditionGroupMemberId) as Members
         from  dbo.ConditionGroupMembers gm 
            group by ConditionGroupId
    )
    select @result=1 from cte c1
    inner join cte c2 on c1.Members=c2.Members and c1.ConditionGroupId <> c2.ConditionGroupId
    return @result
end

  
alter table  dbo.ConditionGroupMembers
add  constraint  CheckDuplicateMembers CHECK (
    dbo.IsDuplicate() = 0)
```

- Note: The above code works, but you can also use a [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of a Check Constraint.

Comment: The code works indead, however i'm not really a fan of the strin_agg usage. In my case the ConditionGroupMemberID is an uniqueidentifier so a cast is needed.
You are correct to state that a trigger would work, but not on the check constraint.
A check constraint does not work because this checks every insert individually, meaning if there is already any of those condition soly in a group, every insert of a group containing that condition would fail